# Why i get this exception when i try to handle empty value on overflow menu?

Tags: android

What i have is an overflow menu on Action bar .. and i have a string called result and what i am trying to do is when this string value is null i want it to display a Toast message instead of navigation to other activity , here is my code :

```
 @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
             Intent m=new Intent(Customer.this,Expendible_list.class);
             Intent i=new Intent(Customer.this,CartList.class);
                super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

                switch(item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.cat:
                         if(result.equals("")){
                               Toast.makeText(Customer.this, "الرجاء اختيار عميل قبل المواصلة", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                           }
                         else{
                          m.putExtra("customer", result);
                            m.putExtra("id", id);
                            startActivity(m);
                            break;    
                         }
                        case R.id.cart:

                             i.putExtra("customer", result);
                                i.putExtra("id", id);
                                startActivity(i);
                            break;  

                }
                return true;

            }
```

But when i click on the first item in the menu my app crash and i see this exception in the logcat :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.customer.Customer.onOptionsItemSelected(Customer.java:398)
at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2548)
```

What is the problem? and how can i fix it?

Comment: which line is **398** of Customer.java

Comment: it's this line  if(result.equals("")){

Comment: Show us the initialization of `result`

Comment: String result; here is my variable

Comment: i fix the problem thx .. it was in initialization

Comment: can you make your comment as an answer so i can vote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to show Toast when **result** is null, so change

```
if(result.equals("")){
```

to

```
if(result == null){
```

or change your initialization as

```
String result = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

In the below line, `result` object is `null`. Since, you don't initialize it properly that's why you are getting `NullPointerException`

```
if(result.equals(""))
```

Before using `result` object make sure that you have initialize it properly and its not `null`...otherwise, you can't get rid of `NullPointerException`.